# How to indicate that an LI with a link was pressed.

Tags: html, css, html-lists, selected

I made a menu and want to keep a pressed button a different color. I.E. If I am at the menu page, the menu button of the menu will be blue.

I have read some online guides about menus and ended up with the following:

```
<div id="menu">

<ul>

    <li>
        <a href="/index.php" >home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/search.php" >search</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>

</ul></div>
```

And the CSS would be something like this:

```
#menu ul li a.selected{
background:blue;
color:#000;
}
```

Of course every `LI` has height and stuff so that it has some color. The question is how can I tell the HTML that a button is selected? The HTML attribute or something?

And another dilemma that I have is how best to change these selected? I can check the address using PHP and change the selected according to it. Any suggestions how to best do it?

Comment: Are you including a menu.php file or is it a different menu each time ? Is the page being reloaded or populated by ajax when clicked?

Comment: I have to -1 because your question title makes absolutely no sense... Let me know if you edit it and I'll un-down-vote it.

Comment: @patsy lssa its the same menu every time not populated by any ajax

Comment: @VoidKing you are right and i have changed the title.

Comment: Ok thnx for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with :

```
<li>
<a href="/search.php" 
<?php 
    if(strstr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "YOURPATH/index.php")) 
      echo "class='selected'";
?>
> Home </a>
</li>
```

or using the Javascript equivalent "document.URL".
Might not be the cleanest solution but should do the thing.

Comment: i will do so, altho i tried to avoid changing the class every time i press a link... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for a use `a:visited` in css. it will be aplicated only if the link was used before

Answer (score 0):

You can use `a:visited` and `a:active` in css.
It becomes `active` when you click on it. It becomes `visited` if you have visited it before.

If you want to manipulate buttons, you might consider using JavaScript (preferably jQuery), then you can easily change element attributes based on actions (e.g. `onclick`).

Comment: thank you, but the button is active only when its beeing pressed. and not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try :active and :focus

```
#menu ul li a:active,#menu ul li a:focus{
    background:blue;
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: hi, the active works only when the button is beeing pressed so its not good for me.